# Ruby on rails 4: Render and/or redirect called multiple times in action. usando Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

en mi controlador registrations_controller.rb en el metodo update, cuando edita y hace los cambios no me redirecciona a la ruta que quiero sino que me marca el error: `DoubleRenderError Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action`.

¿Hay algo que esté haciendo mal en la redirección?
éste es el método de mi controlador:

```
    def update
        super
        @user = User.find(user_params[:user][:id])
        user_params[:user].delete :id
        if user_params[:user][:password].blank?
          user_params[:user].delete :password
          user_params[:user].delete :password_confirmation
        end
    respond_to do |format|
          if @user.update_attributes(user_params['user'])
              format.html { redirect_to users_list_path, notice: 'Usuario modificado con éxito.' }
          else
            format.html { render :edit, notice: 'Error.' }
          end
        end
      end
```

Answer (score 3):

Lo pude resolver. solo se necesitaba agregar un 'return'.

```
format.html { redirect_to users_list_path and return }
```